Set Results Per Page For Google Node.js Youtube API v3 playlists.list() Method
I'm using the Google YouTube Api (v3) to fetch the video IDs for a YouTube Playlist. My code is working well enough, but I'd really like to set the "resultsPerPage" variable to a higher number.  It is set to 5 by default.  I'm using it for album tracks so most of the playlists that I'm working with are between 8 and 15 videos. It would be nice to get all of their info in one call.
When I execute the same request from the Google API Explorer there is no such limitation; it returns all of the videos in one response.
I tried setting the "resultsPerPage" option Node.js code that fetches the data, but that had no effect:
  const youtube_v3 = require('@googleapis/youtube').youtube_v3;
  const youtube = new youtube_v3.Youtube();

  const requestOptions = {
    key: process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails',
    fields: 'items(snippet/title,contentDetails/videoId),pageInfo,nextPageToken',
    playlistId: playlistId,
    maxResult: maxResults,
    resultsPerPage: 10 // this does nothing!
  };

  if ( pageToken ) {
    requestOptions.pageToken = pageToken;
  }

  const results = await youtube.playlistItems.list( requestOptions );
  const data = results.data;

I found some info in the Docs about a PageInfo class. It has a method named  set_results_per_page() which seems promising. However, I have no idea how to access that class.
Has anyone managed to change the number of results per page using the API?

You are looking for maxResults. maxResults: maxResults should solve your issue. Note the s. resultsPerPage is part of the response, not the request as far as I know.

@BenjaminLoison Thanks!  That did it. I see in the docs "Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5." I guess it's the maximum number per page.
